# Why my WPF application becomes slow after a while of minimizing?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

Let's say you have an application developed with WPF, when you run the application and minimize it, after a while (let's say 30 minutes or more), when you restore the window of the application you find that it's frozen (or slow) for a few seconds.

My question is why it becomes slow and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: have you ckecked in task manager if the memory consumption of the application has increased?

Comment: Yes i did, the memory is normal, i think it's something related to the graphics

Comment: THaat worries me much because I am building a big WPF project which I havent test its performance yet...Do you use load of controls in your application?

Comment: @apostolosmeneklis we have a Big Line-of-Business application completely done in WPF and has no performance issues at all. It's actually much faster than its winforms / vb6 predecessors.

Comment: @dries post the relevant parts of your XAML and code. otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: @dries are you sure you don't have any code in window resized events or something like that?

Comment: @dries our WPF application does not exhibit the behavior you're describing here, so it must be something with your code, not something related to WPF itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a property of WPF, it's a property of virtual memory.

Basically, modern operating systems attempt to make the programs that are running as fast as possible - but they also allow many programs to run at once, more than all of their memory could fit into your measely RAM at once. So when the OS sees that a running program needs to allocate a new page of memory, but RAM is full of pages already, it kicks one of the pages (preferring ones that have not been used in a while) to the hard disk, into a file called the page file.

When the program for which that page of memory belonged to attempts to access it, this is called a 'page fault' - the OS detects the page is not in RAM but on disk, and has to read it into RAM before execution continues. This is relatively slow since reading from the hard disk is slower than reading from RAM. If a program hasn't been running for some time, it's conceivable that ALL of its pages have been paged out to RAM - and so it will be slow until it stops hitting page faults.

I'm not experienced with how to deal with this problem, but you can try things like:

1) Writing the program to behave in an asynchronous way - so while one thread is doing things that trigger page faults, the program is otherwise responsive on other threads

2) Deliberately touching every page of your memory to keep it all paged in (Only recommended if your program is so important that it deserves to occupy RAM all the time, even when not in use!)

3) The 'throw hardware at it' solution - buy more RAM :)

Comment: Thank you @Patashu, that's exactly what i wanted to know. to solve this problem, i avoid minimizing my App, so i send it out of the screen (set Position -1000), and made a timer that activate the window each 10 minutes, so it keeps on RAM, and it works fine, thank you.

Comment: @Dries Don't forget to 'accept' my answer if it helped solve your problem.